# How to get source code information from a raw address of jitted .Net function?

Tags: .net, debugging, profiling, clr

I am working on a debugger that should store current stack traces when some function (for example, kernel32.dll!CreateFileW) is being called in the context of a process being debugged.

The debugger injects some code into the process, installs a hook. Then the hook gets stack trace using [RtlCaptureStackBackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-rtlcapturestackbacktrace) and the saves it somewhere.

Then debugger resolves entries of each stack trace using function [SymFromAddr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/ms681323(v=vs.85).aspx).

It works good for unmanaged code.

Today I have tried this approach for an MFC application built with CLR support. Now it's unmanaged code. The hook still gets a stack trace, but the debugger can't resolve some stack entries. I guess these entries belong to the code made by JIT compiler.

I am a bit familiar with CLR profilers and can get notifications like [JITCompilationStarted](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilercallback-jitcompilationstarted-method).

The question is how to resolve (i.e. get source file name and line number) addresses of a code made by JIT compiler?

I can't just call [DoStackSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilerinfo2-dostacksnapshot-method) because the function being hooked can be called really a lot of time, so DoStackSnapshot would make the process slooow.

I could use [FunctionEnter2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/functionenter-function)/[FunctionLeave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/functionleave2-function), but they are called when execution enters/leaves a function and I can't get information about exact code line.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's stated explicitly, it sounds like your question boils down to getting the source position from an instruction pointer, from within a managed profiler.

**Getting the Module, metadata token and IL offset.**

1. The first step is to get the FunctionID, in most cases this will already be given to you, but if not, you can get it from the instruction pointer using [ICorProfilerInfo::GetFunctionFromIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilerinfo-getfunctionfromip-method)
2. Next, you can get the native <--> IL mappings for the function by passing your FunctionID into [ICorProfilerInfo::GetILToNativeMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilerinfo-getiltonativemapping-method). I vaguely recall that the mappings are returned in order, so you might be able to perform a binary search here.
3. Pass the FunctionID into [ICorProfilerInfo::GetFunctionInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilerinfo-getfunctioninfo-method) to get the ModuleID and method metadata token.
4. Pass the ModuleID into [ICorProfilerInfo3::GetModuleInfo2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilerinfo3-getmoduleinfo2-method) to get the path. IIRC, the path will be returned via the `name` argument, but you should check `pdwModuleFlags` to make sure the module exists on disk, otherwise the name won't be meaningful (eg. if the module was emitted).

**Getting the filename and line number.**

This is performed using the [symbol store api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/diagnostics/index) I would suggest doing this part in a monitoring application or post-processing step to avoid holding up the profiler.

1. Get the IMetaDataImport for the module. You can use [CorProfilerInfo::GetModuleMetaData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilerinfo-getmodulemetadata-method) if you are doing this from within the profiler or using [IMetaDataDispenser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/metadata/imetadatadispenser-interface) if you are not in the profiler.
2. Use [ISymUnmanagedBinder::GetReaderForFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/diagnostics/isymunmanagedbinder-getreaderforfile-method), [ISymUnmanagedReader::GetMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/diagnostics/isymunmanagedreader-getmethod-method) and [ISymUnmanagedMethod::GetSequencePoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/diagnostics/isymunmanagedmethod-getsequencepoints-method) to get the IL <--> source mappings.